# Android: How to change the style of a ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-styles, viewpagerindicator

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:padding="@dimen/abc_action_bar_content_inset_material" />
  </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

I'd like to apply a different style to `ViewPager` and `PagerTabStrip` . I tried some of the default styles provided by Android that could change the appearance of a tab bar and indicators but nothing happened.
Please, are there any useful styles for this purpose? Maybe I could inherit and change some attributes.

These are the related declaration in activity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
```

and current style.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to change the colors (accordingly to the theme), you can customize the theme, ex:

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/md_light_blue_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/md_light_blue_700</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/md_blue_a200</item>
    </style>
```

And add a background attribute:

```
<android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/pager_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:padding="@dimen/abc_action_bar_content_inset_material" />
```

Hope i gave you some ideas :)

Comment: Thank you, this is useful. Do you know where I could find some default styles among Android resources?

Comment: if you are referring to colors, replace: @color/md_light_blue_700 with @android:color/black (example)

Comment: More generally I was referring to everything that can be changed: the size of text, colors, background, padding, dividers, etc. I was looking for some of the themes defined by Android to see what attributes I could change and how.

Comment: you could check out these 2 documents:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml

And this would also help also(official guide):  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: Thank you, quite a list! :) Do you know which attribute I should use to change the color of the line below in PagerTabStrip?